# Linker fails with symbol not found with included file from another directory

Tags: c++

I have the following files:

```
..
├── subproject1
│   ├── main.cpp
│   ├── subproject1.cpp
│   └── subproject1.h
├── util.cpp
└── util.h
```

subproject1.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../util.h"

class SubProject1
{
public:
    SubProject1();
};
```

subproject1.cpp

```
#include "subproject1.h"

SubProject1::SubProject1() {
    std::cout << "var is " << VAR << "\n";
}
```

util.h

```
extern const int VAR;
extern const int ANOTHER_VAR;
```

util.cpp

```
const int VAR = 2;
const int ANOTHER_VAR = 3;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "subproject1.h"

int main() {
    SubProject1 project;
}
```

I can get the `.o` files by doing:

```
g++ -c ../util.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c subproject1.cpp
```

But I cannot get the executable by doing:

```
g++ -o main main.o subproject1.o util.o
```

Which instead gives:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_VAR", referenced from:
      SubProject1::SubProject1() in subproject1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're missing `#include "util.h"` in your `util.cpp` file